# rails routes, constraint subdomain and namespace api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having an issue with Rails 4 routes.

When i go to `http://localhost:3000/api/courses`, it tries to render `admin/videos_admin`, and getting this error. But my admin panel works fine.

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/videos_admin"}
missing required keys: [:id]
```

Routes:

```
constraints subdomain: 'admin' do
    resources :videos, controller: 'admin/videos_admin'
end

namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do    
    resources :courses, controller: 'courses'
end
```

also, if I do by this way totally works fine everything.

```
constraints subdomain: 'admin' do
    #resources :videos, controller: 'admin/videos_admin'

    get 'videos' => 'admin/videos_admin#index'
    get 'videos/:id' => 'admin/videos_admin#show'
end
```

I have tried many options, none of them didnt work. 
Thank You !

Comment: Show us the full log please from the server, what you provided doesn't add up.

Comment: @Anthony I have fixed, i had problem in the relation table.